# nHibernate not-found="ignore" and the original field value

Tags: nhibernate

I'm in this situation:

```
Table A
id
name
country
```

and a table of countries

```
Table Country
country
name
```

The field country is the 2-digit ISO (US, PA, UY, etc).
The field country in Table A references field iso in the table Country.
I created the classes on (class A and class Country) nHibernate and because i don't have all the countries i set **not-found="ignore"**.

```
Class A
string name;
Country country;

Class Country
string iso;
string name;
```

If i want to get the ISO code, i will use the .net property of y class, **A.country.iso**.
Now in the case i have an ISO code that is not present in table Country, A.country.iso will give an exception because the country object is null. But the **country** field of table A is not null, i want to get their value.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an additional string property to the `A` class that directly maps to the ISO code column as property. Then you can use that property if the `country` property is null. I'd also mark it as readonly (update and insert false), otherwise it might be confusing for the user of the `A` class which property he should use.

Sample code:

```
public class A
{
    private Country _country;

    public virtual string CountryIsoCode { get; private set; }

    public virtual Country Country
    {
        get
        {
            return _country;
        }
        set
        {
            _country = value;
            CountryIsoCode = value != null ? value.IsoCode : null;
        }
    }
```

Mapping:

```
<property name="CountryIsoCode" column="country" insert="false" update="false" />
```